# Xamarin.Android TextView number different font size

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, string-formatting, textview

I have a question how I can make in `TextView` diffrent font size something like this:

[image]

I found one way is maybe `SpannableString` but I dont know is some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SpannableString` and `SpannableStringBuilder`.

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("25 415,50 XX");
var realtiveSizeSpan = new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f);
ssb.SetSpan(realtiveSizeSpan, 0, 6, 0);
textView.TextFormatted = ssb;
```

This sets a "formatting" for a given character range in the content. The `SetSpan` sets a formatting of a substring, here I set it from index 0, for 6 characters. Note that you  need to assigne the value to the `TextFormatted` property instead of `Text`.

The alternative would be to have two differently formatted `TextView` controls next to each other (wrapped in a `Horizontal` `LinearLayout` for example), but such solution is less reliable and does not ensure that the texts will lay exactly in one straight line.

Comment: can you please give a working example? I don't seem to understand where to place this